# Maven Release using Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm currently trying to use Jenkins Pipeline to deploy the project I'm working on.

The problem appears when I use the following commands:

```
stage("Prepare") {
     sh "mvn -B -s $MAVEN_SETTINGS release:prepare -DreleaseVersion=$releaseVersion -DdevelopmentVersion=$developmentVersion"
}
```

I receive this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release- plugin:2.5:prepare (default-cli) on project *my_project*: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-add command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] /bin/sh: git: not found
```

As you can see, the error is caused by the git add command, which can't be performed.
I have to mention that in a previous stage, in the script, I successfully clone the project, by using a `git url:` command. 
However, if I try a simple git command, like `sh "git --version"`, I get `git: not found`.

So, my question:

In order to be able to use mvn command, I used the next command:

```
env.PATH = "${tool 'maven 3.0.5'}/bin:${env.PATH}"
```

Is it possible to do the same, or any other solution, for git, such that the `mvn release:prepare` will be able to run git add?

Thank you.

Comment: On this node Git is not installed or not provided by Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up running the commands on a docker container, based on an image that had git installed, as I hadn't the rights to install git on Jenkins.